# java - jtable getvalue method not working

Tags: java, jtable, indexoutofboundsexception

i just created a simple Table in java, i'm trying to get data inside row's

```
ArrayList<Object> s = new ArrayList<Object>();

private void get_valuesActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                           
{                                               
    for (int i = 1; i <= mod.getRowCount(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= mod.getColumnCount(); j++)
        {
           System.out.println(mod.getValueAt(i,j));
           //System.out.println("row= "+i+"column= "+j);
        }
    }
}
```

when i count and print rows and columns, it works,

but when using `getValue()`method,it gives the following exception:

`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 >= 1`

i have columns(name,password),why it gives this exception?,what should i do to get data?

Answer (score 1):

In java as in most programming languages you start counting at 0 instead of 1.

This means you should change your for loops to:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= mod.getRowCount() - 1; i++)

for (int j = 0; j <= mod.getColumnCount() - 1; j++)
```

Comment: or just use for (int i = 0; i < mod.getRowCount() ; i++)

Comment: Glad to help you.